# Pull data from view controller on a function

Tags: ios, objective-c

Passing data just isn't doing the trick...I need to pull string data from a view controller when a function in the AppDelegate is called. Here's the code:

In App Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

AMViewController *viewController = [[AMViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AMViewController" bundle:nil];
self.xpData = viewController.xpLabel.text;
NSLog(@"Value of xpString in AD: %@", self.xpData);

}
```

In my ViewController, I'm not using an action to pass/retrieve the string. I'm basically pulling it from the ViewController when the user hits the home button. I'm doing this because I'd like to save my data on exit. Thanks!

Comment: You're creating a view controller when the application enters the background?  how is the xpLabel.text set?  i'm guessing it's not.

Comment: What do you get on your log with the code you wrote? Is it empty, or is it some other value than what you desired?

Comment: `AMViewController *viewController = [[AMViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AMViewController" bundle:nil];` this will create a new view controller. What you need is an existing view controller. How are you creating this view controller? Is it the rootviewcontroller and created in didFinidhLaunching method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (atomic, copy) NSString *yourString;
```

Where you have changed `xpLabel.text`, do this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.yourString = xpLabel.text;
```

Now in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Value of xpString in AD: %@", self.yourString);
}
```

---

Another Method

Set your value in `AMViewController` class like this

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:xpLabel.text forKey:@"yourkey"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Get your Value in `applicationDidEnterBackground` like this

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
yourString = [prefs stringForKey:@"yourkey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried working with [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Or shared delegate:

- http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/
- http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/basic-delegate-example/